# Como corregir la respuesta en una consulta de php y Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: En la siguiente imagen presento una consulta en php y Mysql en la cual imprime PRECESO, FECHA DE INICIO la fecha de termino y días de diferencia son obtenidos de la misma fecha de inicio, la cual se obtiene de con un LAG(dFechaCreacion, -1 ) para obtener el ultimo registro a si mismo la consulta de fecha la almaceno en sus respectivas variables para convertirlas en datos strtotime y poder interactuar con ellas para obtener la diferencia en días, horas y minutos y su redonde. LO QUE NECECITO ES OCULTAR, QUITAR O CAMBIAR EL ULTIMO DATO YA QUE ME APARECE EN DECIMALES, YA QUE NO HAY UNA FECHA IMPRIME EL TIEMPO EN SEGUNDOS ESE ULTIMO REJISTRO DECEO DARLE FIN.]
#En la siguiente imagen presento una consulta en php y Mysql en la cual imprime PRECESO, FECHA DE INICIO la fecha de termino y días de diferencia son obtenidos de la misma fecha de inicio, la cual se obtiene de con un LAG(dFechaCreacion, -1 )  para obtener el ultimo registro a si mismo la consulta de fecha la almaceno en sus respectivas variables para convertirlas en datos strtotime  y poder interactuar con ellas para obtener la diferencia en días, horas y minutos y su redonde. LO QUE NECECITO ES OCULTAR, QUITAR O CAMBIAR EL ULTIMO DATO YA QUE ME APARECE EN DECIMALES, YA QUE NO HAY UNA FECHA IMPRIME EL TIEMPO EN SEGUNDOS ESE ULTIMO REJISTRO DECEO DARLE FIN#

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"style="width: 100%">
              <thead style="background: #BDB0CD;">
                <tr>
                  <th rowspan="2"><center>Proceso</center></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><center>Fecha de Inicio</center></th>
                  <th><center>Fecha de Termino</center></th>
                  <th><center>Diferencia  de tiempo entre cada proceso</center></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <?php
              $listA = $_POST['Id_Orden_de_Produccion'];
              $query_Historial_Sec = $conexion->query("SELECT *,
              LAG(dFechaCreacion, -1 )  OVER (PARTITION BY Orden_Produccion  ORDER BY nIdOrdenProduccion ) as fecha_termino
              FROM historialcambiosordenes AS t1
              JOIN orden_de_produccion     AS t2 ON t1.nIdOrdenProduccion = t2.Id_Orden_de_Produccion
              WHERE t1.nIdOrdenProduccion ='$listA'");
               $total = 0;
                 //El arreglo acciones será como un indice
                 while($datos_Historial_Sec = $query_Historial_Sec->fetch_assoc()){

*En esta parte presento la estructura de las pechas la utilidad del LAG para obtener la segunda fecha solo q el dato final es el que quiero corregir*

                  $fecha2      = $datos_Historial_Sec['dFechaCreacion'];
                  $fecha3      = $datos_Historial_Sec['fecha_termino'];
            
                  $fechaNueba2 = strtotime($fecha2);
                  $fechaNueba3 = strtotime($fecha3);
              
                  $segundos    = $fechaNueba3 - $fechaNueba2;
                  $minutos     = $segundos / 60;
                  $horas       = $minutos / 60;
                  $dias        = $horas / 24;
                  
                  $diasRedondeados = floor($dias);
                  $dataHoras       = bcdiv($horas, '1', 2);
                  $dataMinutos     = bcdiv($minutos, '1', 2);
               ?> 
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><center><?php echo $datos_Historial_Sec['sValorDespues'];?></center></td>
                    <td><center><?php echo $datos_Historial_Sec['dFechaCreacion'];?></center></td>
                    <td><center><?php echo $datos_Historial_Sec['fecha_termino'];?></center></td>
                    <td><center><?php echo $diasRedondeados."  ","Dias";?> - <?php echo $dataHoras. "  ","Hrs";?> - <?php echo $dataMinutos."  ","mts";?></center></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php  } ?>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No explicas muy bien la salida que estas buscando, pero intuyo que quieres la diferencia entre la fecha de término y la de inicio.

Debido a que a veces no existe una fecha de término, cuando se hace `strtotime(null)`, devuelve `false`. Y cuando se hace la diferencia entre  `false - strtotime(fecha)`, PHP internamente interpreta lo primero como `0`, así que la cantidad de días transcurridos serán desde la fecha de inicio hasta el [1ro de enero de 1970](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php). Por eso sale más de **19mil días** y negativo.

Entonces, lo que necesitas es el viejo, básico y confiable: `if`. Si alguna de las 2 fechas es nula o vacía, no hace la operación.
`[*]` No tienes que cambiar tu `while` por `foreach`, en este caso es porque estoy proporcionando la data directamente para hacer las pruebas.

```php
<?php
$data = [
    ['dFechaCreacion'=>'2022-10-04 10:26:56', 'fecha_termino'=>'2022-10-26 16:47:10'],
    ['dFechaCreacion'=>'2022-10-26 16:47:10', 'fecha_termino'=>null],
    ['dFechaCreacion'=>'2022-10-27 08:25:55', 'fecha_termino'=>'2022-10-27 08:25:57'],
    ['dFechaCreacion'=>'2022-10-27 08:25:57', 'fecha_termino'=>null]
];

foreach($data as $datos_Historial_Sec) {
    $fecha2 = $datos_Historial_Sec['dFechaCreacion'];
    $fecha3 = $datos_Historial_Sec['fecha_termino'];
    if($fecha2 and $fecha3) {
        $fechaNueva2 = strtotime($fecha2);
        $fechaNueva3 = strtotime($fecha3);
        
        $diferencia  = $fechaNueva3 - $fechaNueva2;
        $dias = $diferencia / 86400;
        $horas = ($dias - intval($dias)) * 24;
        $mins = ($horas - intval($horas)) * 60;
        $segs = ($mins - intval($mins)) * 60;
        
        echo intval($dias).' dias '. intval($horas). ' horas '. 
            intval($mins) . ' mins ' . intval($segs) . ' segs ' . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo '-' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Y la salida es:

```
22 dias 6 horas 20 mins 13 segs
-
0 dias 0 horas 0 mins 2 segs
-
```

Comment: Exelente gracias de verdad me funciono correctamente